# Why does the parenthesis make a different in this sql query

Tags: sql, sum, case, parentheses

The objective:

> Find the percentage of high elevation airports (elevation >= 2000) by
>   state from the airports table.
>
> In the query, alias the percentage column as
>   percentage_high_elevation_airports.

Could someone explain why the following 2 SQL statements give different results:

Correct result:

```
SELECT state,
100.0 * sum(CASE WHEN elevation >= 2000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / count(*)  as percentage_high_elevation_airports 
FROM airports 
GROUP BY state;
```

sample result:

```
MS  0.0
MT  100.0
NC  11.1111111111111
ND  10.0
```

and wrong result:

```
select 
state,
100.0 * (sum(case when elevation >= 2000 then 1 else 0 end)/count(*)) as percentage_high_elevation_airports
from airports
group by 1;
```

sample result:

```
MS  0.0
MT  100.0
NC  0.0
ND  0.0
```

Only difference is the additional placement of () around the sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT state,
       AVG(CASE WHEN elevation >= 2000 THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) as percentage_high_elevation_airports 
FROM airports 
GROUP BY state;
```

The issue is *integer* arithmetic.  Some databases do an integer division and return an integer.  So, 1/2 is `0` rather than `0.5`.  Some databases also apply this to `avg()` (but even some that do integer division to numeric averages).

I should note that this is database-specific.

Comment: *"I should note that this is database-specific."* SQL standard does define some rules/guidelines  how `AVG()` and how arithmetic should work, but i agree you should test which is portable between database vendors, also because output precision is most often defined as implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not about another/better solution to your query 
but about the wrong results you get with the use of parentheses, right?
Because:

```
sum(case when elevation >= 2000 then 1 else 0 end)
```

results to an integer
and `count(*)` is by definition an integer. 
The division between them is an integer division truncating any decimal digits. 
So you get `0` instead of `0.5` or `0.05`. 
To avoid situations like this you can multiply by a real number like you do: `100.0` first and then divide. 
Or you could do this:

```
sum(case when elevation >= 2000 then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
```

which results in a sum that is a floating point number.
In any case make sure that **at least one of the operands of the division is a real number**.

Answer (score 0):

Try below - you need to change the placement of your parenthesis

```
select 
state,
(100.0 * sum(case when elevation >= 2000 then 1 else 0 end))/count(*)) as percentage_high_elevation_airports
from airports
group by 1
```